# PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit got an ill-formatted floating point number

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this following piece of code and even though I could use pgfplots to achieve the same goal, most of the tikz code are in this way for legacy reasons.

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,
             /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed
    }
    % low pass
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,2) node[left] {$V$};
    \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$f$};

    \draw[line width=1pt, domain=0:4, smooth,
    blue,samples=1000] plot ({\x},{1/(1+(\x/2)^24)}); \draw
    (3,1.5) node[] {lowpass};
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Compiling above gives me the following error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit
 got an ill-formatted floating point number `-56.90549000000000'. The unreadabl
e part was near '-56.90549000000000'..
```

The following package and libraries were used:

```
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz,pgfplots,float}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,er,intersections,decorations,positioning,shapes.geometric,matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
```

What is the reason of the error?

Comment: You cannot use TIkZ with `/pgf/fpu=true`. You have to remove it. https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/678

Comment: If I remove this part, then the error `! Dimension too large` triggers

Comment: Then add `/pgf/fpu=true` *only* to the `\draw plot` and pray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key `/pgf/fpu=true` breaks most of the TikZ drawing code because there is no separation between parsing and formatting, see also https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/678.

However, you can always try to use `/pgf/fpu=true` locally for a single path that is causing `Dimension too large` and pray that it doesn't break anything else.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % low pass
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,2) node[left] {$V$};
  \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$f$};

  \draw[line width=1pt,domain=0:4,smooth,blue,samples=1000,/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed] plot ({\x},{1/(1+(\x/2)^24)});
  \draw (3,1.5) node[] {lowpass};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

```
$ bench "pdflatex test.tex"
benchmarking pdflatex test.tex
time                 1.387 s    (1.226 s .. 1.550 s)
                     0.998 R²   (0.993 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 1.310 s    (1.252 s .. 1.356 s)
std dev              58.24 ms   (26.01 ms .. 76.84 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 19% (moderately inflated)
```

[image]

But if you only want to draw a schematic version of the curve, I recommend that you just use a Bezier curve for smooth corners. This looks pretty much exactly the same but doesn't make the compile time of your document explode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % low pass
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,2) node[left] {$V$};
  \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$f$};

  \draw[line width=1pt,blue] (0,1) -- (1.5,1) .. controls (2.2,1) and (1.8,0) .. (2.5,0) -- (4,0);
  \draw (3,1.5) node[] {lowpass};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

```
$ bench "pdflatex test.tex"
benchmarking pdflatex test.tex
time                 292.8 ms   (277.8 ms .. 302.3 ms)
                     0.999 R²   (NaN R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 298.0 ms   (292.9 ms .. 300.7 ms)
std dev              4.747 ms   (1.946 ms .. 6.257 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 16% (moderately inflated)
```

[image]